# How to loop faster than .each through svg path and polygons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am drawing different svg maps. Each nation will fadeIn and fadeOut. Below I am clicking a `#compbtn` button to load a `.compMap` map using the `.compbtn`. Yet `.each` seems really slow before to process and start the fading of each polygon and path.

How can I loop faster than using `.each`?

**html**

```
<div class="oldmap">SVG old map polygons and path</div>
<div class="newmap">SVG old map polygons and path</div>
<div class="computer_all">SVG old map polygons and path</div>
```

**NOTE:** `.country` and `.shape` are the polygons and path classes i use for the sequential fadings of each part.

**JS**

```
$("#compbtn").on("click", function(i) {
  var $newMap =$('.newmap .country, .newmmap .shape');
  $newMap.each(function( i ){
    $(this).delay(2*i).fadeTo(300,0);
  });
  var $oldmap = $('.oldmap .country, .oldmap .shape');
  $oldmap.each(function( c ){
    $(this).delay(2*c).fadeTo(300,0);
  });
  var lis = $('.computer_all .country, .computer_all .shape'),
  len = lis.length;
  lis.each(function(b) {
    $(this).delay(2*b).fadeTo(500,1, function(){
      if (b === len - 1) {
        $(".oldmap").css("left", "-9999px");
        $(".newmap").css("left", "-9999px");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: A traditional for loop could be faster, but you might want to do some profiling to make sure that's the real bottle neck.

Comment: what do you mean with profiling?

Comment: I very much doubt `.each` is the issue here. Also (separately) note that `.delay(2*i)` is going to be doing **very** short delays which seem unlikely to be perceptible, as the figure is in milliseconds and `i` will be 0, 1, 2, etc.

Comment: I mean doing some performance testing to discover the true bottle neck.

Comment: it is the .each as far as I could see, if i remove that the map and site works fine but obviously i don't have the desidered fading effects

Comment: Have you considered that maybe it's the contents of the loop (the fading effects) that cause the slowdown and not the loop itself? If you leave the .each loop in place but comment out its contents, does it still run slow?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the fading using 2*i works fine actually, its just all very slow before it starts fading, just the start, i guess it is because is looping

Comment: @Juhana why would i leave an empty .each in place? It would certainly be faster as it is empty no?

Comment: That would mean it's not the loop that's slow, but the contents of it, and you need to optimize which ever part of the content is slow.

Comment: ...what? Then why are you asking for a faster loop if you already know the loop is fast enough?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara ok so you are saying using a for loop instead of .each wouldn't be any faster?

Comment: It probably would be slightly faster, but you probably would not notice the difference.

Comment: @rob.m: *"the fading using 2*i works fine actually."* I didn't say anything about *fading* using 2*i.

Comment: @Juhana no. I am asking for a faster loop while you are saying to remove the content and see. Why would Ioop and empty content?

Comment: @rob.m: Because it's not the `.each` that's the problem. Juhana is saying "are things slow with the loop but without its contents?" (I don't think in this case you could tell, but I understand where she's coming from.)

Comment: "@T.J.Crowder you said "which seem unlikely to be perceptible" while it is. Note that the actual fading is fine but the start when i first call the function which is slow and i suppose is because it starts the .each of hundreds of polygons and paths

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Nope, things are NOT slow if i remove the .each bit.

Comment: @rob.m: I said that referring to the **delay**: *"note that `.delay(2*i)` is going to be doing very short delays which seem unlikely to be perceptible"* Nothing to do with fading.

Comment: @Juhana things are NOT slow if i remove the .each bit

Comment: @rob.m: If you remove the `.each` bit, how are you doing the fading and seeing it not be slow?

Comment: @rob.m: You'll need to put a [mcve] ***in*** the question; people shouldn't have to follow random off-site links to help you, and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. The code in the question doesn't even have matching class names between the JS and the HTML.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder right, fixed the classes. The polygons and paths have the classes as I explain. I will try to set a sjFiddle now

Comment: @rob.m: Better to use Stack Snippets (the `<>` button) so it's right here on-site. (Sadly I'm about to be afk, but I'm sure someone can help once you get the MCVE in the question.)

Comment: A kinder user have provided and solved the issue. yes, it had to do with .each and js being heavy and slow while css3 delay solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this effect be done with (mostly) CSS? If I were doing this, I'd loop through each of the shapes and set their custom `transition-delay` property via the `style` attribute when the JavaScript loads, and use CSS selectors in the stylesheet such as `.oldmap.out .shape` and `.computer_all.in .shape` so you only have to edit the markup of the maps with jQuery in order to trigger all their fade effects with their respective delays. *This avoids using a for loop entirely* (at least when you need the transition to kick in).

CSS:

```
.newmap .country,
.newmap .shape,
.oldmap .country,
.oldmap .shape {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.newmap.out .country,
.newmap.out .shape,
.oldmap.out .country,
.oldmap.out .shape {
  opacity: 0;
}

.computer_all .country,
.computer_all .shape {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.computer_all.in .country,
.computer_all.in .shape {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Startup:

```
$('.newmap .country, .newmmap .shape').each(function(i) {
  $(this).css('transition-delay', i/500 + 's');
});

$('.oldmap .country, .oldmap .shape').each(function(i) {
  $(this).css('transition-delay', i/500 + 's');
});

$('.computer_all .country, .computer_all .shape').each(function(i) {
  $(this).css('transition-delay', i/500 + 's');
});
```

Click:

```
$('#compbtn').click(function() {
  $('.newmap, .oldmap').addClass('out');
  $('.computer_all').addClass('in');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick! that solved it. Completly ignored it that I could do it using css3.